# Using 1 HTML form: ask user for unique identifier, get record from database, parse into JSON, populate HTML page form using jquery populate plugin...?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

Let me start by saying that I am not an expert in any one type of code, instead, however, I tend to be okay at piecing things together and making it work!  My latest issue is perhaps a little too technical for my know how.  Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I am using an HTML page with a form to grab a unique identifier from the user.  Then PHP (to grab database information) and JSON (to parse that information into a format for use in HTML).  Finally I am using the jquery plugin “Populate” to send this information into the desired form fields on the HTML page (a separate form from the one getting the unique identifier).

I have a HTML page with 2 forms on it.  The first form:

```
    <form name="form_reservation" id="form-reservation">
        <div style="padding:10px 20px 10px 10px;">
            <label for="reservation-id">Reservation ID</label>
                <input name="reservationid" class="reservationid" style="width:120px !important"/>
                    <div class="json-sample" id="json-simple-sample">&nbsp;</div>
                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Search Reservation" style="width:150px !important; margin:10px 0px 0px 5px;"/>
                    <input type="button" class="button" value="Clear" style="width:150px !important; margin:10px 0px 0px 5px;" onclick="resetForms('reservation')" />
                </div>
        </form>
```

The Javascript to grab this submit is now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    resetForms('reservation');
    $('#form-reservation').submit(function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();  //the page will no longer refresh on form submit. 
        var resCheck = $(this).find('input[class="reservationid"]').val(); //now we have the reservation ID, let's perform our check.
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'inc/searchres.php', 
            type: 'POST', //default is GET, you are using POST(*SEE: [1]) 
            data: 'resid='+resCheck, 
            success: function(data){  //data is all the info being returned from the php file 
                var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);  //parse returned JSON data so we can use it like data.name, data.whatever 
                $('#json-reservation').populate({personal_first_name:jsonData['element_1_1'],personal_last_name:jsonData['element_1_2'],personal_phone_1:jsonData['element_7'],personal_email:jsonData['element_2'],reservation_status:jsonData['ADD THIS CELL'],reservation_date:jsonData['element_3'],reservation_time:jsonData['element_4'],reservation_party:jsonData['element_5'],reservation_special_request:jsonData['element_6'],reservation_using_coupon:jsonData['element_9'],reservation_coupon_code:jsonData['element_10']});
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The purpose of the previous form is to ask the user for a unique identifier.  Once the user clicks “Search Reservation” this unique identifier is used to search a database to see if it exists… This is an external php file called searchres.php (thought I realize this php file is not properly linked to the form, as I couldnt figure out how to do it so the page would not reload or change links):

```
<?php
include('connect-searchres.php');

$term = $_POST['resid'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ap_form_8 WHERE element_1_1 = '$term'"); //select first name (element_1_1) from form #8

if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  //if reservation number exists
    if ($row['element_10'] != 'Cancelled'){  //if reservation has not already been cancelled
        if (strtotime($row['element_3']) >= strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))){  //if reservation has not already passed date
            echo json_encode($row);
        }
        else  //Reservation already passed (old reservation)
        {
            echo 'passed';
        }
    }
    else  //Reservation already cancelled
    {
        echo 'cancelled';
    }
}
else  //Reservation not found
{
    echo 'not found';
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

So to this point, the user has entered their unique number and the php file has searched the database for it.  We have also converted our sql query into JSON format.  I now need to populate the other form from the HTML page with the data that it has received.  The other form looks like (sorry this is a big one):

```
   <form name="json_reservation" id="json-reservation" action="results.php" method="post" target="_blank" style="margin-top:15px">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Personal Information</legend>
                    <ul class="controls">
                        <li>
                            <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
                            <input name="personal_first_name" id="personal-first-name" type="text" class="text" maxlength="" value="" disabled readonly/>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
                            <input name="personal_last_name" id="personal-last-name" type="text" class="text" maxlength="" value="" disabled readonly/>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="personal[country]">Phone</label>
                            <input name="personal_phone_1" id="personal-phone-1" type="text" class="text" style="width:110px !important" maxlength="" disabled readonly/>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input name="personal_email" id="personal-email" type="text" class="text" maxlength="" value="" disabled readonly/>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Reservation Information</legend>
                    <ul class="controls">

                        <li>
                            <label for="status">Reservation Status</label>
                            <input name="reservation_status" id="reservation-status" type="text" class="text" style="width:110px !important" maxlength="" value=""  disabled readonly/>

                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="date">Date</label>
                            <input name="reservation_date" id="reservation-date" type="text" class="text" style="width:110px !important" maxlength="" value="" disabled readonly/>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="time">Time</label>
                            <input name="reservation_time" id="reservation-time" type="text" class="text" style="width:110px !important" maxlength="" value=""  disabled readonly/>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="party">Number in Party</label>
                            <input name="reservation_party" id="reservation-party" type="text" class="text" style="width:110px !important" maxlength="" value=""  disabled readonly/>

                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="specialrequest">Requests</label>
                            <textarea name="reservation_special_request" id="reservation-special-request" rows="3" wrap="virtual" class="specialrequest" style="width:60% !important" disabled readonly/></textarea>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="coupon">Using Coupon/Promotion</label>
                            <input name="reservation_using_coupon" id="reservation-using-coupon" type="text" class="text" style="width:110px !important" value="" disabled readonly/> # <input name="reservation_coupon_code" id="reservation-coupon-code" type="text" class="text" style="width:110px !important" maxlength="" value=""  disabled readonly/>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

So anyhow, this is where I am at, and at this point I know there are A LOT of issues with not only my code, but my method.  Because of that, any tips would be greatly appreciated as I have searched high and low at this point.

Another point to mention, is that I really wanted both of these forms to interact nicely on one HTML page, without reloading it.  External Link can be found:  http://goo.gl/IFVv4  Don't worry about "part 3" of the form on the external link, as that is something I will mess with at a later date.

UPDATE:  I have edited the code above to show where it is I am at now.  Your help was excellent and got me quite far but now I think my problem resides in the php file... thoughts?

Comment: formJSON.json is undefined line 9 in populate-page-functions.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main things I saw here is that you don't understand the process of stopping a form submit, performing a request in the background, and then handling the data that is returned, so I'm going to outline this for you as simply as possible and hopefully it will help.

First, we need to capture the form submit, in jQuery, we can do it like this ->

```
$('#json-hierarchal').submit(function(){});
```

Now that we know how to capture the submit of the form, we need to figure out how to stop the default behavior from submitting and reloading the page, we do this by accessing the [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) argument, and applying the function [preventDefault();](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). (For your sake

```
$('#json-hierarchal').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // the page will no longer refresh on form submit.
});
```

Now that we've stopped the default submit, we can use $.ajax to send the data over to the php file so that it can parse it, and output what we need depending on what we sent.

```
$('#json-hierarchal').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // the page will no longer refresh on form submit.
  var resCheck = $(this).find('input[class="reservationid"]').val(); //now we have the reservation ID, let's perform our check.
  $.ajax({
    url: 'searchres.php',
    type: 'POST', //default is GET, you are using POST(*SEE: [1])
    data: 'resid='+resCheck,
    success: function(data){//data is all the info being returned from the php file
      var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);//parse returned JSON data so we can use it like data.name, data.whatever
      //I don't know how $.populate works, so I'm assuming we find each item returned in the json array, iterate over each occurence, and run populate on it?     
      $.each(jsonData, function(index,value){
        $('#form-hierarchal').populate(value);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**References**

[1] - GET/POST are interchagned based on REST and SOAP practices. When we need to get data from the server we use the `GET method` (We expect data to be returned to the server from the database, or an external file). When we need to post data to the server so that it can be A) Inserted into a Database or B) written to a file (simplicities sake here) we use the `POST method`. It's very important to learn to follow these practices as often as possible.

Comment: UPDATE:  I have edited the code above to show where it is I am at now.  Your help was excellent and got me quite far but now I think my problem resides in the php file... thoughts?

Comment: What does 'data' output when you log it in the console?

Comment: It appears, nothing.  I also added a log for jsonData, but that comes back as 'null'.  I wasnt sure if I needed to access it in some manner differently because it is an array?  That or the data is not being sent correctly from PHP.

Comment: Nevermind, I have figured this out.  Thank you very much for all of your help, not only did you get this working for me but I learned quite a bit too!  I have updated the code above.